# Set non-inclusion proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

$Let$

$A = \{n: n = 2k^2 - 3 \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$B = \{n: n = j^2+3 \text{ for some } j \in \mathbb{N}\}$

To prove $A \nsubseteq B$ we must prove there is some element $x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$. To do this, I think we need to first write $k$ in terms of $j$, then show that the equality does not hold up for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ($A$'s boundaries for $k$) and/or for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ ($B$'s boundaries for $j$)

$$
2k^2 - 3 = j^2 + 3 \Rightarrow 2k^2 = j^2 + 6
$$

Given the equality $2k^2 = j^2 + 6$ we can see that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $j \in \mathbb{N}$ the equality does not hold up as there is some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ($k = 0$ for example) such that there is no $j \in \mathbb{N}$ that can keep the equality true.

If $k = 0$ we prove some element $n$'s membership in $A$ such that $n = 2(0) = 0 \in A$. For $n \in B$ there would have to be some $j: j^2 + 3 = 0$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and since the $j^2 + 3 > 0 $ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows $n \in A \Rightarrow n\notin B$ thus proving $A \nsubseteq B$.

---

Basically given the above proof, I want to make sure for set inclusion and non-inclusion proofs I am looking for the right information. It seems to prove set inclusion or non-inclusion we want to prove that the memberships rules are equivalent or not equivalent. We take the definitions of membership for each set, write them in terms of each other and prove the equality does not hold true for all values of the variables within their respective definitions of membership, which thus means there is some value in one set that follows it's membership rules either can or cannot (depending on the proof) exist in the other set.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, your strategy is fine.

Comment: The procedure you have adopted will lead you to the right answer. However, you haven't answered the question yet, so please do that so we can confirm you are doing things correctly.

Comment: You need to show that there exists at least one member of A that is not also a member of B.

Comment: @DougM I have cleaned up the proof (put $k$ in terms of $j$) and finished it, does it look correct now?

Comment: @DougM In cases like this, do we always want to put $k$ in terms of $j$?

Comment: 0 is not in A.  So that part of your proof is not correct.  You can say 3 is the smallest element in B.  $-1\in A,  -1\notin B$ and be done.